# Jquery/Ajax Refresh without reload or load the page?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a report page which dynamically generate the record and saved in the database. From database i need to show the dynamically updated records in the page without reload or load the contents using setInterval time function.

Comment: Once the new record updated for each second the page getting reloaded, i doknow need to reload full page. i need the only content to be updated dynamically without reload...

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644585/html-change-update-page-contents-without-refreshing-reloading-the-page/3644604#3644604)

and use setInterval function with it

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() 
{
    $("#yourContainer").load('yourPage.php');
}, 5000);
```

offcourse Jquery is prereq for this... so download [jQuery from here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js) and include it in your page

`<script href="yourlink to the file"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

this code http://pastie.org/937213 loads ajax.php to #live div every 3 seconds