# HTML - Change\Update page contents without refreshing\reloading the page

Tags: php, mysql, html, ajax, jquery

I get the data from DB and display it in a div... what I want to do is when I click a link it should change the content of the div

one option is to pass parameter through URL to itself and reload the page...

I need to do it **without reloading\refreshing**...

```
<?php   
    $id   = '1';

    function recp( $rId ) {
        $id   = $rId;
    }
?>

<a href="#" onClick="<?php recp('1') ?>" > One   </a>
<a href="#" onClick="<?php recp('2') ?>" > Two   </a>
<a href="#" onClick="<?php recp('3') ?>" > Three </a>

<div id='myStyle'>
<?php
    require ('myConnect.php');     
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT para FROM content WHERE  para_ID='$id'");

    if( mysql_num_rows($results) > 0 ) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array( $results );
        echo $row['para'];
    }
?>
</div>
```

The goal is when I click any of the links the contents of the div and php variable\s gets updated without refreshing.... so that **user could see new data** and after that if some query is performed it is on new variable\s

p.s I know it is gonna require some AJAX but I don't know AJAX.. so please reply with something by which I can learn... my knowledge is limited to HTML, PHP, some JavaScript & some jQuery

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You've got the right idea, so here's how to go ahead: the `onclick` handlers run on the client side, in the browser, so you cannot call a PHP function directly. Instead, you need to add a JavaScript function that (as you mentioned) uses AJAX to call a PHP script and retrieve the data. Using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recp(id) {
  $('#myStyle').load('data.php?id=' + id);
}
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="recp('1')" > One   </a>
<a href="#" onClick="recp('2')" > Two   </a>
<a href="#" onClick="recp('3')" > Three </a>

<div id='myStyle'>
</div>
```

Then you put your PHP code into a separate file: (I've called it `data.php` in the above example)

```
<?php
  require ('myConnect.php');     
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $results = mysql_query("SELECT para FROM content WHERE  para_ID='$id'");   
  if( mysql_num_rows($results) > 0 )
  {
   $row = mysql_fetch_array( $results );
   echo $row['para'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: can i use
$id = $_POST['id'];
instead of 
$id = $_GET['id'];

Comment: and no more libraries to include besides 'jQuery.js'

Comment: is there a way to do this without javascript/jQuery if I already have the content ready in PHP?

Comment: You are brilliant. Thanks. for posting this.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery will do the job. 
You can use either jQuery.ajax function, which is general one for performing ajax calls, or its wrappers: jQuery.get, jQuery.post for getting/posting data.
Its very easy to use, for example, check out [this](http://www.talkphp.com/vbarticles.php?do=article&articleid=58&title=simple-ajax-with-jquery) tutorial, which shows how to use jQuery with PHP.