# IS there something missing? in Change\Update page contents without refreshing\reloading the page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This question is in reference to

[HTML - Change\Update page contents without refreshing\reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644585/html-change-update-page-contents-without-refreshing-reloading-the-page)

Since the question is protected, I cant go through it.

My question is whether or not something is missing because I can not get it to work.  I have added the jquery library

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

I want to say that the function is not being called, but if I replace

```
$('#myStyle').load('data.php?id=' + id);
```

with

```
document.getElementById("myStyle").innerText = 'text';
```

then it does work and i get text.

Another question is whether or not you could do this or something like it

```
document.getElementById("myStyle").innerText = '$('#myStyle').load('data.php?id=' + id)';
```

Thanks for your help
Jeff

Comment: Are you sure you added jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not using jQuery which is required to use the code in the question you linked to. You also need it to use the `$` shortcut you referenced in your secind question. Start by adding it to your pages and then try the examples again.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use some other JavaScript libraries? Maybe other script/library uses/overrides `$` (namespace, or whatever it is)?

Btw: get familiar with **JavaScript debugger** in your browser.

There is Dragonfly in Opera, Firebug in Firefox, DevTools in Chrome, IE has IE Developer Tools.