# send multiple variables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my first code with jQuery, so be indulgent please. The code below is part of a table in which each row displays: a reload button (Reload.gif), and two comboboxes (cmb1 and cmb2). Here is the edited code for just one row:

```
<table>
<form name="myformname" form action="Handler.php" method="post">
   <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="hidden" name="MyQuestion" value="0">
          <input type="image" src="Reload.gif" border="0"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <select name="cmb1"><option>One</option><option>Two</option></select>
      </td>
      <td>
          <select name="cmb2"><option>A1</option><option>A2</option></select>
      </td>
   </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Variables MyQuestion, cmb1 and cmb2 (user-selected) are passed to Handler.php (as all are in the same form), that search data in databases and reload the page with the new data. **This is working OK.**

But now I want to change the logic, cause I dont want to reload the whole page, but only the row that was clicked. I tried with jQuery something like this (OnClick added to Reload.gif!):

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="hidden" name="MyQuestion" value="0">
          <input type="image" onclick="recp('0')" src="Reload.gif" border="0" name="MyQuestion" value="0"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <select name="cmb1"><option>One</option><option>Two</option></select>
      </td>
      <td>
          <select name="cmb2"><option>A1</option><option>A2</option></select>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And in the header I added this code (I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644585/html-change-update-page-contents-without-refreshing-reloading-the-page))

```
function recp(id) {
  $('#myStyle').load('data.php?id=' + id);
}
```

I got some results for the id, but here is my question:
In the

```
load('data.php?id=' + id)
```

, can I send multiple variables (id, cmb1 and cmb2)?

Comment: `load('data.php?id=' + id + '&cmb1=' + cmb1 + '&cmb2=' + cmb2)`

Comment: You can also send an object: http://api.jquery.com/load/#example-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send multiple variables you could use for example,

```
load('data.php?id=' + id + '&var1=' + var1 + '&var2=' + var2)
```

For more examples and other ways to do it, have a look in the jQuery manual for the [load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

```
$("#myStyle").load('data.php?' + $("form[name=myformname]").serialize());
```