# refresh div using (only using) php without page reload

Tags: php

Is there any way to refresh div by using php (no javascrip, jquery, ajax...). Without reloading my page.

I tried this but it reloads complete page.

```
    <?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "5";
    ?>

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - Change\Update page contents without refreshing\reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644585/html-change-update-page-contents-without-refreshing-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Why can't you use AJAX? It's impossible for `php` too, as that does not have access to the `DOM` which is on the client-side. I think you should read up on how PHP works, it is a server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to refresh any div without reloading of whole page (without using of any form of JavaScript).

... and by the way, as somebody told me some time ago, questions where answer is **YES** or **NO**, are deprecated.

Comment: Thank you Vaclav... and nhee