# Laravel: Change content without reloading the page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to change the `<div id="main">` content without reloading the page.

What is the best method for that? I want to do this for all of the links/buttons on my site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - Change\Update page contents without refreshing\reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644585/html-change-update-page-contents-without-refreshing-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you want is to use a `div` to show the whole app, I recommend using a JavaScript Framework for that.

Check out VueJS and how to integrate it with Laravel on this [free course](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step)

Alternatively, you can check other Frameworks like Angular2, ReactJS, or even jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) to load content and integrate it into your page without reloading the page itself.

See the following links for more information:

[What is AJAX and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009206/what-is-ajax-and-how-does-it-work)

[Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/